# Phantomjs write scraped data to database

Tags: phantomjs

I have written a phantomjs script to scrap Hoover.
Following is my flow:

1:Get data from database using Nodejs API .

2:At a time I fetch 10 rows,pass these rows one at a time to Website,scrap it(the prob is here. I somehow want to store results from Scrapped into a array or something then pass this data back to node API to update database in Azure).

Right now I am able to get data from azure using nodejs API and also able to scrap using phantomjs my only prob is how do I store the results in tempopary storage or array, which then can be passsed to nodejs API for updating database in azure.

Answer (score 4):

*(I'm using CasperJS - it adds a layer on PhantomJS, but I think it might also work in PhantomJS)*

You can have CasperJS do an AJAX call to your backend with the data you want to store.

Make CasperJS include a content script to each page it visits:

`var casper = require('casper').create({ clientScripts:  ['content.js'] });`

Then, in content.js:

```
function sendToServer(theData){
  var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr2.open('POST', your_server_url, true);
  xhr2.send(theData);
}
```

Now you can call `sendToServer` with `casper.evaluate` from your script.

And remember to include this in your receiving app (or see [this module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/cors)):

```
res.writeHead(200, {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
});
```

otherwise your ajax will fail. It is possible that you would have to add OPTIONS route that returns CORS headers as well. Another solution for this is disabling cross-origin checks on PhantomJS with command line switch.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code that how we can call ajax from phantomjs

Comment: @shivaP just updated with moar code. Play with it - it worked in my case (I was using casperjs, which is using phantom and adds some of its own stuff) - in your case you should find similar functionality in phantom (content scripts and evaluate)